# jPOS can not receive ISOMsg from server

Tags: java, jpos

I set the jPOS JAR server step by step by [this](http://jpos.org/doc/tutorials/jpos-gateway.pdf). I create a server by below code :

```
public class jPOSServer implements ISORequestListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Logger logger = new Logger();
            logger.addListener(new SimpleLogListener(System.out));

            XMLChannel serverChannel = new XMLChannel("localhost", 9000, new XMLPackager());
            ((LogSource) serverChannel).setLogger(logger, "server-channel-logger");

            ISOServer isoServer = new ISOServer(9000, serverChannel, null);
            isoServer.setLogger(logger, "server-logger");
            isoServer.addISORequestListener(new jPOSServer());

            new Thread(isoServer).start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean process(ISOSource isoSource, ISOMsg isoMsg) {
        ISOMsg m = isoMsg;
        try {
            m.setMTI("0830");
            m.set(11, "000002");
            m.set(41, "00000002");
            isoSource.send(m);
            return true;
        } catch (ISOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Log in JAR server is here:

```
<log realm="org.jpos.transaction.TransactionManager" at="2019-04-24T15:25:04.787" lifespan="24ms">                       
  <abort>
    txnmgr-1:idle:1
    <context>
      TIMESTAMP: Wed Apr 24 15:25:04 IRDT 2019                                                                           
      SOURCE: org.jpos.iso.channel.XMLChannel@7217f905
      REQUEST:
       <isomsg direction="incoming">                                                                
         <!-- org.jpos.iso.packager.XMLPackager -->                                                                      
         <field id="0" value="0800"/>
         <field id="11" value="000001"/>
         <field id="41" value="00000001"/>
         <field id="70" value="301"/>
       </isomsg>
      RESULT:
       <result>
         <fail>
           [MISCONFIGURED_ENDPOINT] o.j.t.p.QueryHost.prepare:60 'DESTINATION' not present in Context                    
         </fail>
       </result>
      LOGEVT:
        <info>
          RESPONSE not present
        </info>
    </context>
            prepare: o.j.t.p.QueryHost ABORTED READONLY NO_JOIN                                                          
    prepareForAbort: o.j.t.p.SendResponse
    abort: o.j.t.p.SendResponse
    in-transit=0, head=2, tail=2, paused=0, outstanding=0, active-sessions=2/128, tps=0, peak=0, avg=0.00, elapsed=22ms 
    <profiler>          
      prepare: o.j.t.p.QueryHost [20.5/20.5]                                                                             
      prepareForAbort: o.j.t.p.SendResponse [0.8/21.3]                                                                   
        abort: o.j.t.p.SendResponse [0.8/22.1]                                                                           
      end [28.3/50.5]      
    </profiler>         
  </abort>           
</log>               
<log realm="xml-server-8000/127.0.0.1:61804" at="2019-04-24T15:25:07.721" lifespan="3002ms">                             
  <receive>
    <io-timeout/>
  </receive>
</log>
<log realm="xml-server-8000.server.session/127.0.0.1:61804" at="2019-04-24T15:25:07.725">                                
  <session-end/>
</log>
<log realm="org.jpos.q2.iso.ChannelAdaptor" at="2019-04-24T15:29:57.225" lifespan="1ms">                                 
  <warn>
    channel-receiver-jpos-receive
    Read timeout / EOF - reconnecting                                                                                    
  </warn>
</log>
```

I send data by `telnet localhost 8000` to JAR server on port 8000 and JAR server pass data to the server on port 9000. JAR server receives data and log data, send data to Server and server receive data. but `Read timeout` error occurred. I debug the JAR file and found the bug is fired at `b = this.streamReceive();` on BaseChannel.java:777.
How can I fix this? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean bug is in `b = this.streamReceive()`? Your problem seem to be this:

```
        <result>
         <fail>
           [MISCONFIGURED_ENDPOINT] o.j.t.p.QueryHost.prepare:60 'DESTINATION' not present in Context                    
         </fail>
       </result>
```

It means the QueryHost participant doesn't know where to send the message and that's why you are not having a response, you need to add the destination mux to the context, aparently under the "DESTINATION" key. I don't know how you are creating the context, if it is using the IncomingListener you are missing this entry

```xml
<property name="ctx.DESTINATION" value="jPOS-AUTORESPONDER" />
```

Changing `jPOS-AUTORESPONDER` for whatever your mux name is.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I add `
    <property name="ctx.DESTINATION" value="jPOS-AUTORESPONDER" />` to `50_xml_server.xml` but error occurring still.

Comment: I fix the problem only by adding: `m.setMTI("830");` to `process()` method. So at first send data from client to Port 800 (JAR server),  then change the `MIT` of the message, and forward to port 9000. But the problem is I can't understand why I have to change `MIT` in the `process` method and then everything will be ok!

Comment: this is because mux accepts as response only responses. `0830` is a response to `0820` but `0820` is not. You can use also `m.setResponseMTI()`